# How can I create a tunnel/parallax/depth effect based on mobile device tilting?

Tags: unity, 3d

I would like to create applications similar to what's displayed in these videos:

- [VR Tunnel Live Wallpaper for Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8pmhuWqREg)
- [The parallax view Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtBtBwrRi0Q)

These mobile application are supposed to react to tilting of the phone, so I created a few 3D objects for this purpose in Blender (one similar shape - 2nd link), but I do not know how to move the back of this object in Unity because I am a beginner.

Can you give me some tips on how to figure this out? I’m not talking about a ready solution or something, I just do not know how to ask a specific question and I do not know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to investigate how to interact with the phone's gyroscope.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gyroscope.html

You could have a camera locked in place pointing originally at a plane in the distance that represents the black box at the end of the tunnel and have textured planes on each side representing the grid. Then use the gyroscope readings to transform the position of the plane at the end of the tunnel (obviously you can't have it transform too far or you'll get wacky results, so the end of the tunnel needs to be bound within a certain range).

I'm not a Unity developer, but based on the few times I've played around in Unity, that would be my best guess as to how to implement it. The cubes flying towards the end of the tunnel are the easy part.